# Pictures not showins, seems considered as directories

Tags: php, linux, laravel

I would like to show pictures on my website.

Here is the code of the view file :

```
 @foreach($posts as $post)
       <div class="w-full md:w-1/3 xl:w-1/4 p-6 flex flex-col">

        <img src="{{asset("mvbimg/".$post->image)}}" >


        <a href="/news/{{ $post->slug }}">
            @if(!empty($post->image))
         <img class="hover:grow hover:shadow-lg" src="{{ asset("mvbimg/".$post->image."")}}" alt="{{ $post->title }}">
         @else
         <img class="hover:grow hover:shadow-lg" src="https://www.example.com/img/nopic.jpg" alt="{{ $post->title }}">
         @endif
          <p style="text-align: center;">{{ $post->title }}</p></a> 

    </div>

        @endforeach
```

And this is the frontend :
[image: frontend]

This is an URL of a picture upload on the server :
http://127.0.0.1:8000/mvbimg/202204171949lbc1.jpg

And this is my directory :
[image: dir]

Comment: inspect the tag in your browser and see what path you are getting

Comment: will try it soon